# ATtiny85-DHT11-TM1637

Tags: attiny, temperature-sensor, 7-segment

I have tried many combinations and I can get the Attiny85 to display on the TM1637 just fine, but I cannot get ant readings from the DTH11, tried different pins, libraries. I upload code via UNO as isp and that works fine. Tried same code on UNO and it works.

This is my first question on here, I usually figure things, but also first ATtiny85 adventure.

[image]

```cpp
#include <TM1637Display.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#define CLK 4
#define DIO 3
#define DHTPIN 2  //
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
int MTD (2000);
TM1637Display display = TM1637Display(CLK, DIO);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

const uint8_t celsius[] = {
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_F | SEG_G, SEG_A | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_F
}; // oC
const uint8_t Fahrenheit[] = {
  SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_F | SEG_G, SEG_A | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G
}; // oF
const uint8_t Humidityh[] = {
  SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G, SEG_C | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_B
}; // HU

void setup() {
  dht.begin();
  display.setBrightness(7);
}
  
void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  float Humidity = dht.readHumidity(); 
  float TemperatureC = dht.readTemperature();
  float TemperatureF = dht.readTemperature(true);

  display.showNumberDecEx(TemperatureF, 0b10000000, false, 2, 0);
  display.setSegments(Fahrenheit, 2, 2); delay(MTD);
  display.showNumberDecEx(Humidity, 0b10000000, false, 2, 0);
  display.setSegments(Humidityh, 2, 2); delay(MTD);
  display.showNumberDecEx(TemperatureC, 0b10000000, false, 2, 0);
  display.setSegments(celsius, 2, 2); delay(MTD-1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found <TinyDHT.h> and all works ok, just what I wanted.